# Cabal "Data Files" Not Being Copied

Tags: haskell, cabal, data-files, hsenv

I'm trying to use the "data-files" mechanism, and stuff works fine **except** that the
relevant files are **not** copied into the `share/` directory. e.g. my .cabal file looks like:

```
name:                nano-js
version:             0.1.0.0
data-files:          include/prelude.js
```

but after building and installing the directory

```
.hsenv/cabal/share/nano-js-0.1.0.0
```

does not exist. So queries of the form

```
getDataFileName "include/prelude.js"
```

yield a `FilePath` that does not exist

```
nanojs: /home/rjhala/research/liquid/.hsenv/cabal/share/nano-js-0.1.0.0/include/prelude.js: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

Are some extra keywords required to populate `share/`?

Or could this be an issue with `hsenv`?

Thanks!

Comment: I honestly can't remember why, but I believe you had to list the files under `extra-source-files` as well.

Comment: Please, make your edit an answer instead

Answer (score 3):

I was being silly -- the `data-files` clause needs to be at 
the top while I had it buried in the executable section...!